# Rendering formated text with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend

Sorry if you find this question silly or off-topic but I have the following issue. I am experimenting with ReactJS and trying to write simple blog-like Single Page Application.

I want users to write posts on my blog with rich features for text decoration. So I am going to allow them to use some html tags. The problem is: what is the best way to render users' input data?

I simply can get their html input, escape dangerous html tags (like script etc.), and then just use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render raw html. Is it a good approach? Are there some ReactJS specific features to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could allow them to use markdown? This way you could escape all html tags input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you can, avoid `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`. This is also stated in the offical [react documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

One possible approach would be to define a specific input format as @canaan seaton stated. 
My idea would be to use a component like [draftjs](https://draftjs.org/) to render rich text content and to give the editors the ability to see what they get (wysiwyg). Draftjs is really easy to understand and there are plenty resources and additional packages (like syntax highlighting, ...) out there.

Off course you can also use any other rich text editing component.